# 2 Objects have the same Particle system setup

Tags: particles

So I made an object and realized that I majorly screwed up. So I manually selected vertices (sorry if I spelt that wrong) and seperated that, making a new object. Anyways, whenever I edit the particles of the 2nd object, it also changes the first one's particle system. If there is any way to make them different, please tell me. Thanks for reading! :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to click the number button next to the particle selection.

[image]